# Change order of fields per node

Tags: entities

So i know how to order fields when creating/editing a content type. But say i have three fields in a content type:

- name
- last name
- nick

and want these to be draggable when a user creates a new node.

Any suggestions?

Thx!

Comment: WHAT IS YOUR DRUPAL VERSION?

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 7, you can use the Field Weight module to change the field order per node.
http://drupal.org/project/field_weight

I've used it with no trouble.

Comment: That module is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

In cck you can change order of content type fields, and with [Field display weights module](http://drupal.org/project/field_weight) you can have different order of fields **per node** . by default drupal **not have a module for ordering field in view** (we should order them in back-end part .
I think if you want fields be dragable in view(fornt-end)  you should to use [jquery ui dragable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458665/drupal-jquery-ui-draggable-stacking-divs) help you to provide your needs

Comment: Unfortunately that module you referenced for changing the weights of the fields seems to no longer be maintained.